# Python exponentiation order of operations and grouping

Tags: python, time, operators, exponentiation

Simple question:
Why does `(7**3) ** 24 % 25` take almost no time to run, but `7 ** 3 ** 24 % 25` not terminate?

Comment: operator precedence ..

Comment: @wim What specifically? If `%` takes precedence over `**` then it would compute 343 to the power of 24 which takes almost no time. Otherwise it's the same as the fast expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exponentiation groups [from right to left](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

So, `7 ** 3 ** 24` is evaluated as `7 ** 282429536481` (hard), whereas `(7**3) ** 24` is just `343 ** 24` (easy).

---

As an interesting sidenote: CPython, which has a peephole optimiser, is able to optimise away the "easy" case with constant folding.  But the "hard" case only gets as far as folding the `3 ** 24`.

```
>>> def foo():
        return 7 ** 3 ** 24 % 25
... 
>>> def bar():
        return (7**3) ** 24 % 25
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (7)
              3 LOAD_CONST               5 (282429536481)
              6 BINARY_POWER        
              7 LOAD_CONST               4 (25)
             10 BINARY_MODULO       
             11 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               7 (1L)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: OOOOOOOOH yes! that's the same as in regular math. Sorry I'm stupid.

Comment: Yeah, 1.6910144928582986e+238680647722 is pretty big. :-)  Of course if we only care mod 25, we can use the 3-argument form of pow to get the result quickly.

Comment: When it's written with superscripts the order is obvious but in this notation I didn't realize what was going on.

Comment: `pow(7, 282429536481, 25)`  :)